# Archive custom template from search

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search, archive-template

I'm using this code for a dropdown of categories. On selection of the dropdown the desired category is displayed using the archive template. I cannot for the love of me get the template hierarchy to work.

```
<form>
<select name="tag-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value='#'>Select Taxonomy terms</option>
<?php $taxonomies = array('service-category');
$args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>true);
echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args); ?>
</select>
</form>
```

I am using a custom post type called 'services' and a custom taxonomy 'service-category'. Is there a way to tell the search to use a different archive.php template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) - you should be able to use `taxonomy-service-category.php` template to display `service-category` posts.